# How to trigger v-show on Component B from Component A

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-directives

I am trying to show a component when a button is clicked on another component.

I have tried using props but it didn't work, I am probably doing it wrong.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Would you please provide us any solutions you've already tried yourself?

Comment: Hi Node Shack, your question is currently not really answerable, because we do not know what kind of relation "Component B" and "Component A" have. In this case different relations call for different solutions, but without any code it is a wild guess as to what you really need. Please create a [mcve] to improve your question. You can do this by clicking the edit button under your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey so it depends of where the component is situated, but generally a button will be on the "internal" component commonly referred to as the child component (as it is placed inside of the "parent" component) in this case you would need to emit upwards and then react to the event in the parent, would look something like this:

```
//Parent
<template>
   <childWithButton @buttonClick="doSomething"/>
</template>
.
.
.
methods: {
   doSomething(){
     ....<
}
}
...
//child ("childWithButton")
<template>
  <button @click="$emit('buttonClick')></button>
</template>
```